# Getting Headers are read-only, response has already started error in ASP.NET Core 8.0 Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

Using ASP.NET Core 8.0 Blazor with a button that when pressed executes the code:

```
await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext!.SignInAsync(...);
```

Throws the following error: *Headers are read-only, response has already started*

This happens with both `@rendermode InteractiveServer` and `@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly`

Example:

```
@page "/MyPage"
@inject IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
<button @onclick="DoSomething">
    Do Something
</button>

@code {
    private async Task DoSomething()
    {
        //Code Logic
        await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext!.SignInAsync(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you try without any render mode?

Comment: @RuiLima I believe the function DoSomething() will not be called without the page being either InteractiveServer or InteractiveWebassembly. Only a form can be submitted, which does a full post of the page, can be used in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on ASP.NET 8 Blazor, then you can use an SSR (Server-Side Rendering) page with a form to solve this issue.

See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8uBemyBs8Zk for how to use a form in an SSR page, but do not use the StreamRendering that is demonstrated later in the video, if you do then you will get the "Headers are read-only, response has already started".

Example:

```
<form @formname="MyFormName" @onsubmit="SubmitAsync" method="post" data-enhance>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <AntiforgeryToken></AntiforgeryToken>
</form>
```

Code Behind:

```
private async Task SubmitAsync()
{
    await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext!.SignInAsync(...);
}
```